# Can I reference a relationship to a relationship?

Tags: relationships, low-events

I have a channel, Events. Sometimes there's an event that's repeating, and I don't want my content authors to do that all over again. So I have another channel, Events Repeating, which has a Relationship field back to Events and a Date/Time field (Low Events), so it only takes defining those two fields (which event and when) to essentially duplicate an event.

So any time somebody looks at the Events calendar, they see both Events and Events Repeating entries. Works great.

There's just one field that I'm having trouble with: Contact, which is a Relationship field in Events to my Profiles channel. When referencing this from Events Repeating, that means a relationship to a relationship.

In Events Repeating, my Relationship field to Events is called "Event"; in Events, my Relationship field to Profiles is "Contact".

Thus, I tried: event:contact:first_name, to no avail. Is this supported? Or should I try something else?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I need a tag loop to do this. e.g., this doesn't work:

{event:contact:first_name}

This works:

{event}{event:contact:first_name}{/event}

Comment: FYI, this, if used in an "if" conditional, would need to be wrapped on quotes. e.g. {if "{event}{event:contact:first_name}{/event}" != ""}